# how to set jboss.bind.address.management and jboss.bind.address.unsecure to the same value as jboss.bind.address?

Tags: jboss, bind, ip-address

JBoss 7.1.1.Final question:

Is there any way that jboss.bind.address.management and jboss.bind.address.unsecure can be set to the same value as jboss.bind.address without hardcoding them in standalone.xml or passing them as command line parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interface addresses accept expressions. The default values look like the following:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <!-- Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
             To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL -->
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Since they are expressions they could easily be changed to use the same property value like so:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <!-- Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
             To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL -->
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Comment: I don't like the language that JBoss uses.  It should be either a "subnet interface" OR an "ip address", not a hybrid of that terminology.  Calling a interface an "address" is really confusing.